# Firestore | Local storing data without sync to Firestore server

Tags: ios, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

**Requirement:** Is there any way of using local cache of Firestore to store data without publishing it to the Google server?

- Data should be read from locally.
- Sync of the data should not happen with Firestore server.

**Note:** Please suggest solution without storing data using CoreData or any other native api.

Comment: You can use Realm to store data locally > https://realm.io/

Comment: Yes but as Firestore also support local caching of data write for offline conditions. So I was wandering if there is any way to keep it unsung for time being and later publish it, so that I don't have to rely on any other database.

Comment: Hi, did you ever resolve this issue? We have data that we need to store locally until the user manually pushes it to the firestore.

Comment: Stopped using firestore as our requirements got changed. Not sure if they released any functionality around.